# How to use a phrase to describe a situation that you meet a problem can't be solved?

Tags: phrase-request

Assuming this :

**I was doing some work step by step, then I blocked at somewhere and I have tried all the solutions I could find, spent a lot of time, but the problem still can't be solved.**

I want to use "*I have some trouble in* ..." or "*I have a difficulty in*..." to describe it, but I think they are not fit very well and a little casual. How do you people describe this situation in written English and Spoken English?

Comment: I have/I'm having (some) trouble/difficulty solving/trying to solve this problem, or maybe I'm having/I have a hard/difficult time solving/trying to solve this problem.

Comment: The problem is [*insurmountable*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/insurmountable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really can't think of anything else to try, you can say any of the following:

> I'm [stuck](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stuck)!
>   I'm [stumped](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stump?q=stumped).
>   I've reached a dead end.
>   I can't see a solution.
>   I can't see a way forward.